# Why does the div get created on top of another div in javascipt?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a project and I want button to create a div when it is clicked.But on my second click; system creates the div on top of another.

```css
#Car-adder-div{
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
}

#Car-name-text{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 98px;
}

#Car-name{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid lightgray;
}

#Car-price-text{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 98px;
    top: 90px;
}


#Car-price{
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 40px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid lightgray;
}


#Submit-button{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='Auto_gallery_page.css'>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Car-adder-div">

        <!--Name input-->

        <h1 id="Car-name-text">Name</h1>

        <input id="Car-name" type="text">




        <!--Car price input-->
        
        <h1 id="Car-price-text">Price</h1>

        <input id="Car-price" type="text">


        <!--Submit button-->

        <input id="Submit-button" type="button" onclick="Addcar();" value="Add a car">


    </div>

    <script>

        function Addcar(){

            var car_name=$("#Car-name").val();

            var car_price=$("#Car-price").val();

            var car_div=document.createElement("div");

            car_div.style.position="absolute";

            car_div.style.width="320px";

            car_div.style.height="80px";

            car_div.style.left="300px";

            car_div.style.top="20px";

            car_div.style.top+=car_div.style.top;

            car_div.style.border="2px solid #d3d3d3";

            document.body.appendChild(car_div);             
            
            

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are absolute positioning the new divs with the exact same absolute co-ordinates for each of them. Use relative positioning instead for the created divs, and instead of setting the width/height via the style attribute, set a class on the new divs and apply styles via a stylesheet.